# When should I use parallel-programming?

Tags: algorithm, parallel-processing

What could be a typical or real problem for using parallel programming? It can be quite challenging to implement. On the internet they explain how to use it but not why.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Performance is the most common reason to use parallel programming. But: Not all programs will become faster by using parallel programming. In most cases your algorithm consists of parts that are parallelizable and parts, that are inherently sequential. You always have to reason about the potential performance gain of using parallel programming. In some cases the overhead for using it will actually make your program slower. Have a look at [Amdahl's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law) to learn more about the potential performance improvements you can reach.

If you only want some examples of usage of parallel computations: There are some classes of algorithms that are inherently parallel, see this article [the dwarfs of berkeley](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/16721939/EECS-2006-183.pdf)

Comment: Link is broken! : the dwarfs of berkeley

Comment: Actually, Amdahl's Law and Gustafon's Law are the best for answering this question. I wrote an [article](https://medium.com/@kelvinmuchiri/just-because-you-can-write-parallel-programs-it-doesnt-mean-you-should-29cc65fb8096) on this

Answer (score 2):

Another reason for using a multithreaded application architecture is it's responsiveness. There are certain functions which block program execution for a certain amount of time, i.e. reads from files, network, waiting for user inputs, etc. While waiting like this does not consume CPU power, it often blocks or slows program flow.

Using threads in such case is simply a good practice to make the code clearer. Instead of using (often complex or unintuitive) checks for inputs, integrating those checks into program flow, manual switching between handling input and other tasks, a programmer may choose to use threads and let one thread wait for input, and the other i.e. to perform calculations.

In other words, multiple threads sometimes allow for better use of different resources at your computer's disposal: network, disk, input devices or simply monitor.

*Generalization*: using multiple threads (including parallel data processing) is advisable when the speed and responsiveness gains outweigh the synchronization costs and work required to parallelize the application.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why there is increased interest in parallel programming is partly because the hardware we use today is more parallel. (multicore processors, many-core GPU). To fully benefit from this hardware you need to program in parallel.

Interestingly, parallel processing also improves battery life:

- Having 4 cores at 1Ghz draws less power than one single core at 4Ghz.
- A phone with a multicore CPU will try to run as much tasks as possible simultaneously, so it can turn off the CPU when all work is done. This is sometimes called "the rush to idle".

Now, some programs are more easy parallelize than others. You should not randomly try to parallelize your entire code base. But it can be a useful excersise to do so even if there is no business reason: then you will be more ready the day when you really need it.

Answer (score -3):

There are very few problems which can't be solved more quickly by a parallel program than by a serial program.  There are very few computers which do not have multiple processing units.

I conclude, therefore, that you should use parallel programming all the time.

Comment: e.g. For batch programming, there is no reason to parallel each task. The overhead of most parallel programs would decrease the throughput.

Comment: Sometimes the extra development time for parallelising a difficult task is greater than the total time saved for all executions of the task itself.  So I don't think you can say that you should use it all the time.

Comment: I think it is generally accepted that optimizing your non parallelized algorithm gives usually more performance gains for less effort than trying to parallelize it. This is why I downvoted "I conclude, therefore, that you should use parallel programming all the time".